# Bricked Onda v919 64gb (without 3g)

Tags: tablet, windows, dual-boot, onda-tablet

I currently bought a tablet Onda v919 from China. When I received it I realized that the installed android did not contain Google Play, and after reading about it I found out that you could make an upgrade with a later rom to fix this. I followed a guide to do this, but after I finished my tablet will not start.

When booting I enter what I think is the efi console.

To fix this I have tried to reinstall windows from backup images. However I have not been able to make a bootable usb drive.

Does anyone have any tips on how to reinstall my tablet?

Best regards
David

Comment: Why are you trying to "reinstall Windows" on an Android tablet? It seems unlikely that your tablet would even boot from a USB drive.

Comment: Oh, I realize my question was not that clear. It is a dual boot device but now does neither android or windows start.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have corrupted your partitions. To fix this you either need to rebuild your partitions (which requires a knowledge of the device and MBR or GPT, and will need know how the factory ROM is imaged).

Or you can repartition your tablet by flashing it with a factory ROM. This will revert the tablet back to its original state. Thus erasing all of your data.